# How to fix a background-color?

Tags: css, gradient, background-color, fixed

My question, can seem very dumb. But it's not, even I think so.

I've got a gradient on my background-color to make an effect on the background-image which is under it with position fixed.

```
body{
  background-image:url(...);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(89,148,202,1) 62%,     rgba(95,154,207,0.7) 68%, rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
}`
```

I hope, I've been precise enough. If you need more information, don't hesitate.

Thank you !

Comment: The problem is what exactly?

Comment: So what are you trying to accomplish? Example?

Comment: I just want to put a gradient over a background-image. And nothing has to moove when I scroll down. I hope you will understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you want:

- a fixed background image on the body
- and a fixed background on top of that, obscuring most of the background image

you'll need to add

```
top:0; left:0;
z-index:-1;
```

to the `body::after`, and change its `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`.
The z-index is necessary, because otherwise the ::after would be on top of the content of the body itself.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xhd35/1/).